# How to add Typescript Interface for a ReactRouter's PrivateRoute?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-v4, react-props

Im using React Router v4 and has created a private route, along the following lines:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                return isUserLoggedIn() ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

And it is used like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <PrivateRoute path="/vehicles" component={Vehicles} />
</Switch>
```

Now, I get the following error:

> Binding element 'Component' implicitly has an 'any' type.

This is because, I have given noImplicitAny AND I have not specified Interface type for this PrivateRoute props.

Question is, **How do I add interface to the props here?**

Note: It is especially the ...rest part in the props, that Im primarily confused at typescripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
export interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps  {
    component: Component;
}

const PrivateRoute = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {
    let { component: Component, ...rest } = props;
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                return isUserLoggedIn() ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Where should the Component be imported from? (Im getting this error: [ts] Cannot find name 'Component'.)

Comment: Em, it's from your code. If you want pass any react component, then use  something like React.Component.